# display files and dir in linux as graphic mode

Tags: linux

how to display the directories and files in graphic way

I forget the command in linux but some linux command can displayed from root directories the recursive directories like this

root

```
|
```

sbin  etc   var ...

```
|   |     |

dir dir dir dir ........

|   |   |   | 
|   |   |   |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use the [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) program. It's distributed along with the popular GNU/Linux distros and is much more durable than a shell pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

For an output like

```
|-root
|---dir00
|-----dir01
|---dir01
```

[Try this](http://www.centerkey.com/tree/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use this :

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

Pay attention, this command will recursively list all files in the current directory, so don't run this command from the root directory ;)

Comment: I would recommend `tree` instead of a shell pipeline like this.

Comment: Well, I have tried it on my Ubuntu Server machine and this command wasn't found. So the this shell pipeline is more universal.

Comment: `apt-get install tree` works for me. It's written in C so it's faster and more feature rich than the shell version.